# Avg. velocity in plane polar coordinates

Tags: kinematics, coordinate-systems, vectors, calculus

It's fairly easy to describe velocity, acceleration and displacement in plane polar coordinate system is the time interval is approaching to 0, but how can we calculate velocity, acceleration and displacement in a finite time interval i.e the average velocity and acceleration.

Comment: What prevents you from working backwards from the fact that you already know the correct behaviour of these things in Cartesian coördinates and know the way to translate between polar coördinates and Cartesian coördinates?

Comment: because unlike in the cartesian coordinate system the unit vectors over here are also changing as the body moves

Comment: Correct, but that is a complication that can be handled. Just a lot of maths. The issue, however, is the limited usefulness; is the answer you seek worth the effort needed to get to it?

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on starting with polar coordinates, you'd do,

$$\vec v _\mathrm{avg} = \dfrac 1{t_2-t_1} \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \vec a \, \mathrm dt = \dfrac{\vec v_2 - \vec v_1}{t_2-t_1}$$

and you express this in terms of the unit vectors for velocity at times $t_1$ and $t_2$.  But you'd wind up with a set of 4 linearly dependent basis vectors (assuming 2D motion).

From there, if you want to get to an orthonormal basis of two vectors (i.e. two unit vectors that are perpendicular to each other), you'd pass by cartesian coordinates, and either keep your average velocity in that form, or, if you wish, express it in terms of the basis vectors of either $\vec v_1$, $\vec v_2$, or whatever else.

TLDR, you end up passing by Cartesian coordinates anyway, so it boils down to calculating the average velocity in cartesian coordinates, and then using whatever coordinate transform to express them in whatever system you choose to.